# A couple more problems with my horizontal subnav...but almost there

Tags: html, css, nav

So I've been working on what I was helped with yesterday and I'm so close. My code is much cleaner now. I have 2 issues that still need resolving. I've been trying all morning and can't seem to get it.

1. I need to control of the height of the subnav. I had to change the height in "ul li a" to 100% from pixels so at least now it just wraps around the text, which is ok, but I will probably need to change that height eventually and don't want to do it by increasing the font size.
2. - ANSWERED - I added a margin-down in % to the subnav and you'll see why based on the design. The problem with this is that once you slowly move the mouse over the white space the sub nav disappears. If you do it fast enough you can sometimes catch it. I had the same issue with the vertical spacers within the subnav but did some rearranging in the css and it seems to be fixed now. Any suggestions?
3. Can I have the single worded links center without compromising the vertical centering with the multi-worded links?
4. Is there a better way to add in "margins or buffers" instead of the "spacers" I'm using, or is this "okay"?

http://codepen.io/Compton/pen/iwKJm

--UPDATED CODEPEN--

http://codepen.io/Compton/pen/ufGCI

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by the margin you added to the `.subnav` class: while moving the mouse from the upper list item to the sub list, the mouse had to move over a gap of 0.333% space resulting in a lost focus (or lost hover-effect). I updated your code and removed the unnecessary spacers, the updated version can be found here:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hzAaD
Referring to your original code, change your CSS as follows:

```
 .subnav ul li {    
   margin: 0;
   margin-top: 3px;
 }
 .subnav {
   width:100%;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! The code you supplied above helped with my subnav issue but unfortunately what you suggested for the spacers won't achieve what I need. Aegis suggested the same in their answer. I need all the content within my nav to stretch. A margin-right or left won't help me do this as it will always give a buffer area to whichever side you choose to add the margin on. Like I said to Aegis, spacers aren't ideal in any way but they get the job done in this instance.

Comment: You're welcome. I tried to fix the margin problem using a combination of `li {margin-left: 5px;}` and `li:first-child {margin-left: 0;}` but that still didn't work as expected, the parent ul will still use a width as if all elements had a left margin of 5px. I updated the CodePen but now you'll see an extra margin on the sub navigation items. Switching from `ul-li` to `div-div` may be an alternative because you'll likely miss some display rule the browser may apply to a vertically aligned list per default.

Comment: @ SaschaM78 - I appreciate the help but I think I may have to stick with the spacers for now. No, it's not the best way by any means but it could be much worse I suppose. Luckily, if I ever need to go back it won't be a major bug or anything too hard to fix. We need a new type of padding rule. Maybe something that acts like a magnetic field that only affects over like elements.

Comment: @Compton I forked your latest CodePen and restructured the CSS to use inline-block rather than table-cell CSS (side-note: IE8 still has some problems with `display:table-cell;`, especially if no outer table and table-row elements exist). Table cells normally don't have a fixed width, instead width is calculated based on the available width of the surrounding table (which doesn't exist) that's why the spans didn't center. CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lepri

Comment: Totally forget to mention, my last edit should take care of point 3 from your list ;-)

Answer (score 1):

For point four, you don't need to add an empty list item for every "space" between each list item, this is bad practice as a list item is meant to actually be used for something, not empty space!

Instead, why don't you simply amend your ul li class so that you add a margin-right property:

```
ul li {
    float:left;
    width: 14%;
    display:block;
    **margin-right: 5px;**
    text-align:center;
}
```

This will achieve the same effect as having those spaces so you can remove them from your html.

Comment: I understand that spacers are bad practice but adding a margin right doesn't help my situation of needing the nav to strecth 100%. I don't want extra space in there. See what I mean? The spacers may be bad practice but it works absolutely perfectly. 

Updated Pen - http://codepen.io/Compton/pen/wEAht

Comment: are you saying that you want each of the colored blocks to touch up against each other?

Comment: @A2345sooted - Sorry, when I say I don't want extra space in there I mean that I don't want the extra space from the margin on the far right link. Using a margin will always give me this problem. Margin-right works fine until you get to that last link.

Comment: @A2345sooted - I guess I didn't answer your question. No, I don't want them to touch up against eachother. I'd like a buffer zone without having to use a margin right or left.